# Highcharts heatmap background color when no data

Tags: highcharts, background, heatmap

That's my first question:

If a heat map does not contain any data or has only 0, then the background appears black. How can I change it to white?

`data: [[0, 0, ""], [0, 1, ""], [0, 2, ""], [1, 0, ""], [1, 1, ""], [1, 2, ""], [2, 0, ""], [2, 1, ""], [2, 2, ""]],`
http://jsfiddle.net/Apacs/bwm54gfa/

Comment: It's black because you are using strings in place of the value. I mean this: `[0, 0, ""]` - if you don't have a value, then use `null`: `[0, 0, null]`

Comment: Thank you! Now the background ist grey, not white. See example. Any ideas?
http://jsfiddle.net/Apacs/bwm54gfa/2/

Comment: Because these cells are empty? See: http://jsfiddle.net/bwm54gfa/3/ Anyway, you can always change [`nullColor`](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#plotOptions.heatmap.nullColor). ;)